Swapping tokens using web3py
I'm learning web3 py righn now and trying to do a swap from USDT to ETH using ShibaSwap service.
I didn't add code for approving because I already have sufficient amount of approved tokens!
Here's my code:
import asyncio
import time
import aiohttp

from web3 import Web3

from data.config import ABIS_DIR
from eth_async.utils.utils import read_json

rpc = 'https://rpc.ankr.com/eth/'

contract_address = Web3.to_checksum_address('0x03f7724180AA6b939894B5Ca4314783B0b36b329')
# importing contract abi from different file here
abi = read_json(path=(ABIS_DIR, 'shibaswap.json'))


async def get_token_price(from_token, to_token) -> float | None:
    from_token, to_token = from_token.upper(), to_token.upper()
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(
                f'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol={from_token + to_token}') as r:
            result_dict = await r.json()
            if 'msg' in result_dict and 'Invalid symbol' in result_dict['msg']:
                async with session.get(
                        f'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol={to_token + from_token}') as r:
                    result_dict = await r.json()
            return float(result_dict['price'])


async def main():
    web3 = Web3(
        provider=Web3.HTTPProvider(
            endpoint_uri=rpc,
        )
    )

    # my private key is there :) 
    pk = ''
    account = web3.eth.account.from_key(private_key=pk)
    wallet_address = account.address

    contract = web3.eth.contract(abi=abi)

    from_token = Web3.to_checksum_address('0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48')
    to_token = Web3.to_checksum_address('0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2')
    slippage = 1
    usdt_amount = 2
    deadline = int(time.time()) + (25 * 60)
    amount_out_min = float(usdt_amount) / await get_token_price('ETH', 'USDT') * (1 - slippage / 100)

    base_fee = (web3.eth.get_block('latest'))['baseFeePerGas']
    max_priority_fee = web3.eth.max_priority_fee
    max_fee_per_gas = int((max_priority_fee * 2) + (base_fee * 1.05))

    data = contract.encodeABI(
        'swapExactTokensForETH',
        args=(
            usdt_amount * 10 ** 6,
            int(amount_out_min) * 10 ** 18,
            [from_token, to_token],
            wallet_address,
            deadline
        )
    )

    tx = {
        'chainId': web3.eth.chain_id,
        'maxPriorityFeePerGas': max_priority_fee,
        'maxFeePerGas': max_fee_per_gas,
        'nonce': web3.eth.get_transaction_count(wallet_address),
        'from': web3.to_checksum_address(wallet_address),
        'to': web3.to_checksum_address(contract_address),
        'data': data,
    }

    # error happens here
    tx['gas'] = web3.eth.estimate_gas(tx)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    res = asyncio.run(main())
    print(res)


The problem is that I face that error when I try to estimate gas:
    raise ContractLogicError(message, data=data)
web3.exceptions.ContractLogicError: ('execution reverted: TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED', '0x08c379a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000245472616e7366657248656c7065723a205452414e534645525f46524f4d5f4641494c454400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000')

For reference I'm using transcation that I made before via ShibaSwap directly, using their website, so I'll leave it's hash (if it helps). I'm using etherium network:
0xdd112b8299e61e68255a1e5bfb1c9edf19acbf7820d680c0344cf561cb6bee80 
I checked all the inputs in data variable and they seem to be almost identical as in transcation that I did before myself. I also don't think that problem might be with gas calculation.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
